# Datetime syntax error

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, stored-procedures

I'm newbie at SQL Server. I'm stuck on a problem that I can't solve. I want to write a stored procedure.

`TimeStamp` column's datatype is `datetime`.

This my stored procedure:

```
    @fetchtype int,
    @startdate nvarchar(22),
    @finishdate nvarchar(22)
AS
    if (@fetchtype = 0)
    BEGIN
        PRINT('Select TimeStamp ' From WindData Where TimeStamp between '+@startdate+' and '+@finishdate)
        EXEC('Select TimeStamp ' From WindData Where TimeStamp between '+@startdate+' and '+@finishdate) 
    END
```

An also my execution query is

```
DECLARE @return_value int

EXEC    @return_value = [dbo].[Get_Values]
    @columnnames = N'V81_Avg',
    @fetchtype = 0,
    @startdate = N'2013-04-23 12:58:40.000',
    @finishdate = N'2013-04-23 12:59:00.000'

SELECT  'Return Value' = @return_value
```

But when I execute my query I get this error

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
>   Incorrect syntax near '12'.

I think I didn't write properly datetime format.

Comment: In the above example you definitely have unequal number of opening and closing quotation marks. Not sure if that is the problem or just typo here. I guess typo, and the problem is likely with (lack of) converting between `datetime` and `varchar`. But unsure of what exactly until you fix the quotations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is in SQL query string:

It should be:

```
PRINT('Select TimeStamp From WindData Where TimeStamp between '''+@startdate+''' and '''+@finishdate+'''');
EXEC('Select TimeStamp From WindData Where TimeStamp between '''+@startdate+''' and '''+@finishdate+'''')
```

But the best way is to use these parameters as DATETIME and avoid dynamic query and replace `EXEC()` with just SELECT:

```
@startdate datetime,
@finishdate datetime

...
Select TimeStamp From WindData Where TimeStamp between @startdate and @finishdate;
...
```

Comment: startdate & enddate are nvarchar here and the above query will not get correct results

Comment: @AnandPhadke: Why not? SQL Server will convert them to datetime automatically in this dynamic SQL. But as I've written the best way os to use datetime parameters and avoid dynamic query.

Answer (score 1):

You need to put quotes around the dates:

```
declare @sql nvarchar(max) = 'Select TimeStamp From WindData Where TimeStamp between '''+@startdate+''' and '''+@finishdate+'''')
EXEC(@sql);
```

Or, better yet, use `sp_executesql`:

```
declare @sql nvarchar(max) = 'Select TimeStamp From WindData Where TimeStamp between @startdate and @finishdate')
exec sp_executesql @sql, N'@startdate date, @finishdate date', @startdate = @startdate, @finishdate = @finishdate;
```

Comment: OMG !!! Putting Quotes ' ' in a DateTime.now into SQL text solved my problem ! I never would have thought to put Quotes in a DateTime value , like i never would have put Quotes in an integer value.

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE PROC yourSPName
(@fetchtype int,
@startdate nvarchar(22),
@finishdate nvarchar(22)
)
AS
DECLARE @sqlstr varchar(2500)
if (@fetchtype = 0)
BEGIN

Select TimeStamp From WindData Where TimeStamp between convert(datetime,@startdate) and convert(datetime,@finishdate)

END
```